# Vuejs buscar en un campo de texto en el nodo raiz y actualizar dos componentes

Tags: javascript, html5, vue.js

He creado un nodo raiz con dos componentes, en el nodo rais tengo un campo de texto para buscar, el cual es enviado a cada componente para buscar en un arreglo de enlaces (links) y que con el resultado renderizar cada componente. Adicionalmente a cada componente le envio la referencia de una funcion para que cada componente notifique si no tiene elementos. Pero cuando ingreso el texto en el formulario la consola me arroja este mensaje:

> [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render
>   function.
>
> found in
>
> --->

Codigo:

```
var links =[...];
var links2 =[...];

var template = `
<section class="section has-text-centered" v-if="searchBy.length > 0">
    <section class="container">
        <p class="subtitle has-text-dark">{{subtitle}}</p>
        <section class="columns is-multiline ">
            <section class="column column-fixed" v-for="link in searchBy">
                <a  v-bind:href="link.url" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;"> 
                    <strong> {{link.title}} </strong>
                        <figure class="image is-96x96">
                            <img class="" v-bind:src="link.img"> 
                        </figure>
                </a>
            </section>
        </section> 
        <hr>
    </section>
 </section>
`


Vue.component('links',{
    props:['links','subtitle', 'search'],
    template:template,
    computed:{
        searchBy:function(){
            if(this.search !==''){
                var _links = this.links.filter((link)=>{
                    return link.title.toLowerCase().search(this.search.toLowerCase()) == 0
                })
                console.log('_links: ', _links);

                (_links.length > 0)? this.$emit('empty',false):this.$emit('empty',true);
                return _links;
            }
            return this.links;
        }
    }

})



new Vue({
    el:"#links",
    data:{
        brand:"Enlaces",
        title:"Acceso Rápido",
        subtitle_private:"Guardián del ALBA - PDVSA",
        subtitle_public:"Públicos",
        links:links,
        links2:links2,
        search:'',
        thereAreLinks:0
    },
    methods:{
        linksEmpty(status){
            console.log('hay resultados: ', status);
            (status)?this.thereAreLinks++:this.thereAreLinks--;
        }
    }
})

contenedor de componentes:
<div class="container">
                <links :links="links" :subtitle="subtitle_private" :search="search" @empty="linksEmpty"></links>
                <links :links="links2" :subtitle="subtitle_public" :search="search" @empty="linksEmpty"></links>
                <h2 class="title has-text-centered" v-if="thereAreLinks > 1">
                    No results: <span class="has-text-danger">{{search}}!</span> 
                </h2>
            </div>
```

Alguna idea del error o una mejor solución?

Comment: @JuankGlezz, gracias, no me percaté.

Answer (score 0):

Hola señor Antony Petrocelli

Hace tiempo que esta esta pregunta, a lo mejor ya resolviste el problema, pero de todas maneras...  Mejor que sobre y no que falte.

El problema me pasó mucho a mi también y la solución es no hacer el  "emit" en una propiedad computada  (computed) es mejor en method, luego haces referencia a ese a esa función dentro del computed asi:

```
Vue.component('links',{
props:['links','subtitle', 'search'],
template:template,

methods:{

vacio:function(estado, valor){

this.$emit(estado,valor);

}

}, 
computed:{
    searchBy:function(){
        if(this.search !==''){
            var _links = this.links.filter((link)=>{
                return link.title.toLowerCase().search(this.search.toLowerCase()) == 0
            })
            console.log('_links: ', _links);

            (_links.length > 0)? 
this.vacio('empty',false):this.vacio('empty',true);
            return _links;
        }
        return this.links;
    }
}

})
```

Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Wilmer, eso fue un ejercicio, pero es interesante saber de una solución, aunque ahora me gustaría saber la causa, sera una regla de vue. Gracias.